# Is a combination of 'space is big' and 'humans haven't been around long' a good solution to the Fermi paradox?

Tags: fermi-paradox, seti, drake-equation, astrobiology

The Fermi paradox is basically that:

1. There are billions of stars, life is probably abundant throughout the universe.
2. Even though it may take tens of thousands or millions of years for life on other planets to reach us, the universe is old enough that they should have reached us by now. (eg. a civilisation that developed space travel 100 million years ago could have explored the entire Milky Way.)

But is it possible that, yes aliens have reached earth, but they reached earth perhaps a million years ago, documented the life currently existing, and haven't bothered coming back?

What's wrong with this explanation?

Comment: Why would other civilizations want to make contact with us or explore the universe? What might be rare is the desire to explore the universe.

Comment: I prefer this solution from [smbc-comics](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=1919)

Comment: What if intelligence at some point turns into an intensive rather then an extensive development - and so colonization of any sort is just simply not interesting to it.

An example: 
If a human's consciousness will be possible to migrate into a fully digital world (as suggested by some scientists it will be possible within 100 years) - like Flatline's mind in Neuromancer - and also we continue the development in the nanotechnology - then at some point maybe the whole humanity will not take up more space then a walnut. so why colonize...

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Another [smbc-comic](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3183) for this.

Comment: Related [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/638/)

Answer (score 10):

A couple of issues with the Fermi paradox:

1. The Fermi paradox is closely tied to the [Drake equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation). This equation is the best method we currently have for thinking about the probability of intelligent life in our galaxy. The problem is that there are so many assumptions you have to make in that equation, that the results vary drastically. If you plug some of the more negative assumptions into the formula, you get as few as only 2 civilizations currently in our galaxy.
2. To say that an advanced civilization would even bother to colonize the rest of the galaxy is a big assumption. Our forefathers colonized every place they could. Today, we have wildlife reserves where we specifically try to limit human interference. We take great care not to spread Earth life to other planets when we send science probes. Maybe a sufficiently advanced civilization will simply choose not to colonize everything.
3. The more advanced a civilization becomes, the easier it is for them to wipe themselves out entirely. This is the view Carl Sagan took to explaining why we have not yet made contact with other intelligent life. If some rulers decided to wage war even 100 years ago, they could not wipe out all humanity even if they tried. If we detonate every nuclear bomb we have in stockpile today, the odds of even 1 human surviving is about zero. We are doing science experiments like trying to create black holes, creating catastrophic climate change and breeding ever more deadly viruses. The odds of us wiping ourselves out in the future seem to be increasing every year.

Comment: 2 *"To say that an advanced civilization would even bother to colonize the rest of the galaxy is a big assumption."* To say that NO civilization ever has colonized the galaxy is an even bigger assumption. It is a claim about how all of them always have been without any exception. The motive of human space flight, the cold war politics of the Sputnik and Apollo, would be pretty difficult to explain to an alien. We shouldn't expect to understand why they travel, but since they can, as we can, some of them will do so some of the time.

Comment: 3 I disagree. Once a civilization, or a branch of a tree of life, goes interstellar, it becomes immortal and will exist for ever after. No comet or supernova or war can wipe it out. It is as reversible as boiling an egg. Civilizations that colonize will be the most common type of civilizations, with time more common than microbial life, purely for evolutionary reasons. And please note that human population grew every year even during the second world war. Don't overestimate our ability to destroy ourself.

Comment: @LocalFluff Errr.... didn't they lately discovered a method to restore protein shape/order back exactly on the example of boiled egg? http://livescience.com/49610-scientists-unboil-egg.html. I still agree with the point, but the example is kinda missed... or maybe it does indicate something.

Comment: @LocalFluff point 2 is supplementary to point 1. If there are only 2 civilizations out there, there is a strong possibility that neither will choose to colonize. I agree that if there are 100000 civilizations, it would be strange that not even ONE of them ever colonized

Comment: @LocalFluff Note that we as a civilization have not yet gone interstellar. Even if we do successfully colonize Mars, we would not be immortal. To create a colony on Mars that can survive with no dependency on Earth will probably take another 100 years. In the past 100 years, we have created more extinction level risks than ever before in known human history. There is a significant possibility we won't ever go interstellar. This raises some questions to how many interstellar civilizations could actually be out there. I don't disagree with you, I'm just saying there are too many assumptions.

Comment: @neelsg Isn't it more prudent to assume that all imaginable kinds of civilizations are or have been out there, than that all of them, without any exception ever, share some common property which prevents them from going interstellar? Especially since they cannot coordinate when the time lag for communication is thousands of years. Once a civilization goes interstellar it is all over the galaxy for all time to come. Interstellar civilizations must be much more common than planets with indigenous primitive life. There cannot be 2 civs out there. There must be either none or many millions.

Comment: Re *If you plug some of the more negative assumptions into the formula, you get as few as only 2 civilizations currently in our galaxy* -- It's easy to come up with much more negative assumptions than that, yielding as few as 2 civilizations in our galaxy group. And that might be the answer. Escaping star systems with sufficient resources and capabilities to colonize a galaxy (or parts thereof) is hard. Escaping galaxies to colonize a galaxy cluster is orders of magnitude harder.

Comment: *If we detonate every nuclear bomb we have in stockpile today, the odds of even 1 human surviving is about zero* — is that so?

Comment: @DavidHammen The Frankenstein laboratories have not yet discovered any particular obstacle for life to originate spontaneously. Life as we know it uses the most common elements and molecules under common circumstances. And our way of life has been so totally successful that it originated under very hostile conditions and not only sustained itself during billions of years, but spread into every single drop of water on the entire planet. I doubt there can be a more efficient way of life than ours. I bet that aliens with independent origin will be DNA-based and (multi)cellular too.

Comment: *If we detonate every nuclear bomb we have in stockpile today, the odds of even 1 human surviving is about zero* -- Nah. Civilization would likely collapse horrifically, and billions might die, but the species would almost certainly survive.

Comment: @RussellBorogove There are something like 5000 active warheads representing more than 1000 Megatons yield. For comparison, the warhead dropped on Hiroshima was 0.016 Megatons. Detonation of all these warheads at the same time would mean more than a collapse of civilization. It would be interesting to see an actual scientific model though. Interestingly, our stockpile used to be much larger during the Cold War

Comment: I seriously doubt even detonating all of the nuclear weapons would cause more than 90 percent of humanity to be extinguished. Your typical thunderstorm releases as much energy as a Hiroshima class weapon (10^15 joules), and a hurricane about 10^17 joules per day. I am also willing to be that the radioactivity is also not so great, compared to the sum total of mining activities, coal burning, etc.

It would surely be very horrible and lead to some dark ages though.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer to your question is "yes".  The combination of "space is big" and "humans haven't been around long" is a valid (as opposed to good) explanation for the Fermi paradox.

I replaced "good" with "valid" because "good" is subjective and can be colored by one's own opinions, and desires, about the possibility of alien life.  But as logical explanations go, yes, I think this is perfectly valid reasoning.

After all, we don't really know how hard it may be to break the FTL barrier.  Maybe it really is impossible for all practical reasons, and since space is so big, alien species don't come around very often, and certainly not for no good reason.  As far as colonization is concerned, you're going to pick the low-hanging fruit first - that is, the compatible systems that are closest will be the first to be colonized.  And, even if you are aware, through remote detection, that other compatible systems are out there, you're not going to need to go until you're pretty well established with the closer ones.

Comment: I don't really buy your 'lowest hanging fruit' explanation, as the time scales involved would suggest that, unless we live on the very corner of the universe, that those closest systems would have already been populated and we'd be discovered.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone anywhere anytime did space travel, they should have been here by now. The Milky Way is small compared to its age and travel times. The Sun has made about twenty orbits around it. The dinosaurs actually lived on Earth when it was on the other side of the galaxy. Either we are alone as a space faring society, or we have company very close by. The most unlikely scenario is that "they" exist but are far between. As if a part of the ocean had no fish.

Interstellar distances and the constant speed of light ensures that space faring civilizations, even colonies with the same origin, cannot be coordinated. When the communication time lag is thousands of years then technology, culture, policy will evolve completely differently. So if anything is out there, then everything is out there. If Stephen Hawkings is afraid of a dangerous type of aliens, he can rest assured that they, if anyone, do exist and that they are nearby. There are nice guys out there too, everyone is out there, they just cannot be similar to each other.

But that logic has no support at all from observations. All life on Earth is related to each other and had the same origin. You and I have some genes in common with every living cell be it a dog, an insect, a fungus or a disease. We are all family since over three billion years. Nothing ever came here to change that. And the ancient surfaces of the Moon and Mars, where we now can find our own small spacecrafts from orbit, show no signs at all of any artificial manipulation. We are definitely alone as a space faring society in the solar system, and we always have been. This in spite of the fact that the Sun has been all around the galaxy many times and has had many different neighbors.

And SETI has showed us that if they exist then they don't like to use radio very much. Nor do they rebuild galaxies or build Dyson spheres around stars. If we do have neighbors, then thankfully they aren't very noisy. Thinking about it, none of them ever was, which is a bit creepy. Like being all alone in a gigantic hotel, like in the movie The Shining. Your mind begins to make up ghosts as company.

Comment: We cannot be sure that no ET life has ever arrived. Maybe *we* are ET! We'll never know for sure.

Comment: @andy256 We can't prove a negative. But I think that the untouched surface of the Moon is an especially convincing argument against any "visitors" during the last billions of years. We have ourselves already left traces there. Just as a byproduct of political prestige.

Comment: Ah, you misunderstand me - I was referring to the [panspermia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia) hypothesis.

Comment: @andy256 If panspermia exists, it only came once to Earth. All life on Earth obviously has a single common origin since over 3 billion years. Like all other hypothetical answers to the conundrum I know of, it isn't very satisfactory.

Comment: Agreed. Even if we produce life in a test tube, the "spontaneous ignition" theory is still unproven. The strongest evidence one way or the other would be finding life beyond Mars, and see if it's related to us or not.

Comment: Re *The most unlikely scenario is that "they" exist but are far between.* Why? To me, that is the most likely scenario, and it is the easiest answer to the Fermi paradox.

Comment: @DavidHammen Because if one once goes interstellar, it will live forever. And the rotation of the galaxy slowly moves them to everywhere around here in the disc among billions of stars. More primitive life should be more common, but only up to the threshold of going interstellar. Primitive life, and advanced but non-traveling civilizations, stay put on its planet of origin and terminates with its star if not sooner. Interstellar life on the other hand goes everywhere and lives forever, they become more common. Its the logic of variation and selection. Don't you think its applicable here?

Comment: @LocalFluff, *Because if one once goes interstellar, it will live forever.* That's nonsense. Nothing will live forever. All stars eventually die, and eventually there will be no new stars. The Drake equation is bad enough, based on a sample size of one. Your reasoning is based on a sample size of zero.

Comment: @DavidHammen Red and white dwarfs could support life for trillions of years. But exolife relevant to us is about what is and has been. Going interstellar is a way for "a tree of life" to sidestep alot of potential extinction scenaria. Maybe it didn't work for everyone, but once is enough. It is a very annoying conclusion, I don't know what to do with it, but there it is.

Comment: @LocalFluff - That is conjectured, not known. We don't know what conditions were necessary for life to arise because we don't know how life arose.

Comment: @DavidHammen We don't know, but one way to help learn about it is to imagine different scenaria and extrapolate them. If the consequences don't match our observations, we can say that scenario is unlikely. It is not known how life came about. But it is also not known what would prevent life to arise. What is most sober, to assume that life is common as it is and has been on Earth for the last billions of years, or that we are miraculously unique? Both options are mad, and a compromise saying that there are about two or three civs in the Milky Way, is just a bad excuse.

Comment: I'd like to address a few issues with your answer: 1) There's no evidence of them here. - That assumes that aliens would colonize earth or otherwise leave evidence. It's perfectly plausible that alien life would take a 'hands off' approach.

Comment: 2) We can't see radio waves. Sure good point, but radio noise from earth peaked after what 75 years? It's plausible that aliens are using wired in communication...

Comment: 3) Seeing Dyson spheres - interesting point. I'm not convinced that Dyson spheres are realistic (is there enough material and energy to create them?). Also, perhaps we don't have the technology to detect them. Remember our technolgy is only a couple of thousand years old. Consider it might be a bit like trying to detect a B2 bomber with WWII radar.

Comment: While speculative, I think this is the best answer currently posted. The most we can do, pending finding evidence of life (microbial maybe) either in the past of Mars, the present of Europa, or on a nearby exoplanet, is to say, "it is really weird!" Nice point about the lack of visible engineering artifacts, be they Dyson spheres, remains of mining on the Moon or Mars, or something on the scale of pulsars that are of clearly intelligent design.  

Possibly we're too stupid to "see" the answer why - we're just recently out of the Serengeti pondering what advanced minds might do or think.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to extend that a bit, to "(Technological) humans haven't been around long, and on present evidence aren't going to be around all that much longer".  If the average lifespan of a technological civilization, from the point at which it can produce radio waves (or other emissions) that could conceivably be detected from another star to the point at which it destroys itself through ecologial degradation, averages about two centuries, what's the probability that two will exist simultaneously, close enough for one to detect the other?

Comment: This is my parent site.